# How do I format a number as a string, so that zero is replaced by the empty string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need for this to work in a single format statement and to work for both ints and decimals:

For example:

```
int myInt=0;
decimal myDecimal=0.0m;

// ... Some other code

string formattedResult1=String.Format("{0}",myInt);
string formattedResult2=String.Format("{0}",myDecimal);
```

The expected results are:

"" (i.e., string.Empty) if the item to be formatted is zero
and a numeric value (e.g., "123.456" for the decimal version) if it isn't.

I need for this to occur exclusively as a result of the format specification in the format string.

Comment: "I need for this to occur exclusively as a result of the format specification in the format string". Can you write and call an IFormatProvider? That was going to be my answer but have deleted for now as not sure from question if that would be acceptable or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do:

```
string formattedResult1 = string.Format("{0:0.######;-0.######;\"\"}", myInt);
```

The colon introduces a numeric format string. The numeric format string is divided into 3 parts with semicolons: part 1 is for positive numbers, part 2 for negative numbers, and part 3 for zeros. To define a blank string you need to delimit it with double quotes otherwise it doesn't like it.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for the full syntax.

Comment: Nice in theory but doesn't seem to work?

? string.Format("{0:0;0;}",0)

"0"

Comment: string.Format("{0:0;0; }",0).Trim() would work, but there has to be a better way?

Comment: Sorry, I keep updating my answer. See current version. :-)

Answer (score 1):

based from the accepted answer above i have done the same thing in microsoft "report builder"

this worked for me (shows 2 decimal places, blank for zero) :

## ,##0.00;-#,##0.00;""